# i got some problem when i want to build my recycle view project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

please give me solve about my error, i got this problem when i want to make recycle view in my project with image copied into my drawable. this is the error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
     Required by:
         project :app
  > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
  > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable **offline mode** from Android studio settings.